# Get stored procedure name while executing error dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering, why SQL Server is unable to the error_procedure while executing the dynamic SQL in a procedure. It is possible for me to invoke the procedure name in the error message in scenario 2?

Scenario 1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_PROCEDURE] 
AS 
BEGIN
   EXEC SELECT 1/0
END
GO

EXEC TEST_PROCEDURE
```

Error message:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TEST_PROCEDURE, Line 6
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

Scenario 2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_PROCEDURE] 
AS 
BEGIN
     EXEC('SELECT 1/0')
END
GO

EXEC TEST_PROCEDURE
```

Error message:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: Uh, your first scenario is getting an error when creating the procedure because you don't have the right syntax. EXEC executes a stored procedure (there is no stored procedure "SELECT"). EXEC() executes whatever parameter you put inside the brackets. To output a custom error message with the procedure name, put a TRY CATCH statement into your procedure and put a custom error message in your CATCH.

Comment: Thank for reply! Yea, i figured out that i can use the TRY CATCH mechanism to get the procedure in scenario 2. Aside then that, is that any alternative?

Comment: There isn't really an alternative. TRY CATCH is the only way to capture specific error information. Note also that if you're executing something within a stored procedure, SQL may give misleading information with regards to errors. e.g. If you have 100 lines of code then add `EXEC('SELECT 1/0')` to the 101st line, it'll say there was an error on Line 1 (because that is the first line of the code that is being executed).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_PROCEDURE] 
AS 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC('SELECT 1/0')
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @Err VARCHAR(255);
        SELECT @Err = 'Error in TEST_PROCEDURE. ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        RAISERROR(@Err, 16, -1)
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) `ERROR_PROCEDURE()` built-in function to get the procedure name in MSSQL. Alter your procedure like below by adding TRY CATCH.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_PROCEDURE] 
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY

 EXEC('SELECT 1/0')

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
DECLARE     @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
            ,@ErrorSeverity INT
            ,@ErrorState INT
            ,@ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(128)

SELECT  @ErrorMessage   =   ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity  =   ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState     =   ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorProcedure =   ERROR_PROCEDURE();

RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,   
           @ErrorSeverity,
           @ErrorState,
           @ErrorProcedure)
END CATCH;

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

END
```

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TEST_PROCEDURE, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Divide by zero error encountered.